# "Flat" component formatting in Flex using 4.14.1... but not in debugger

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm using Flash Builder 4.7, Windows 10, and Apache Flex 4.14.1 to update a mobile app.  In the debugger the app looks correct but when I put it on an iPad, iOS 8, it flattens all the components.  For example, a button has no edges or definition, just the title on the button shows. It shows fine on my iPhone 3gs.

How can I get this to display properly on the iPad?

Comment: What version of iOS are you running on your iPhone?

Comment: I'm using 8.4.1 on the iPad and 6.1.6 on the iPhone.

Comment: I should also say that it's been fine on the iPad until I installed 4.14.1.  Previous versions were ok.

Comment: This sounds like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-34758, but that was supposed to be resolved in 4.14.1.  How are you specifying skins for the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

On the device, iOS8 skins are used automatically.  If you want the legacy mobile look, you can follow the steps here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=50856172